# Count of SQL Server OS types for each month of last 12 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the task of creating a report that should show the different operating system types of SQL Servers in our environment for each month of the last 12 months.

I created the following table and data is loaded inside every day:
[image]

I need to get OS types for each month for the last 12 months to be displayed in the following format:
[image]

I wrote the following query but it is wrong. The struggle I have is how to get the OS types count for the last data collection of each month (not last day of each month) and display the Date in format `Mon YYYY`. I use SQL Server 2008 R2. Any ideas?

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT OSVer = CASE OSVer
                       WHEN '5.0.2195' THEN 'Windows Server 2000'
                       WHEN '5.2.3790' THEN 'Windows Server 2003'
                       WHEN '6.0.6002' THEN 'Windows Server 2008'
                       WHEN '6.1.7600' THEN 'Windows Server 2008 R2'
                       WHEN '6.1.7601' THEN 'Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1'
                       WHEN '6.2.9200' THEN 'Windows Server 2012'
                       WHEN '6.3.9600' THEN 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
                       ELSE OSVer
                  END,
           Date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Date) ORDER BY Date DESC) as rn
    FROM dbo.SQLMachines
    WHERE OSName IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT OSVer, Count(OSVer) AS 'Count', Date
FROM cte
where rn = 1
GROUP BY OSVer, Date 
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions to get the last day with data for each month, and use that to select the appropriate row:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT OSVer = CASE OSVer
                       WHEN '5.0.2195' THEN 'Windows Server 2000'
                       WHEN '5.2.3790' THEN 'Windows Server 2003'
                       WHEN '6.0.6002' THEN 'Windows Server 2008'
                       WHEN '6.1.7600' THEN 'Windows Server 2008 R2'
                       WHEN '6.1.7601' THEN 'Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1'
                       WHEN '6.2.9200' THEN 'Windows Server 2012'
                       WHEN '6.3.9600' THEN 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
                       ELSE OSVer
                  END,
           Date,
           MAX(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)) as maxDay
    FROM dbo.SQLMachines
    WHERE OSName IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT OSVer, Count(OSVer) AS cnt, CAST(Date a Date)
FROM cte
WHERE CAST(Date as Date) = CAST(MaxDay as Date)
GROUP BY OSVer, CAST(Date a Date) 
ORDER BY CAST(Date as Date) DESC;
```

The `cast()`s are only needed if `Date` has a time component.